# How to get sound on Microsoft Teams notifications only if @ mentioning me (or a call or meeting)?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get Microsoft Teams to be less distracting.

I only want to get interrupted with high priority things:

1. A meeting is starting soon.
2. Someone is calling (or a meeting call is starting now).
3. Someone @ mentioned me.
4. Someone DM's me (a chat where I am explicitly a member, not to a group I'm in.)

This is on Windows 11 with the paid (business) version of the New Teams version.

What configuration would I use?